# iOS 9 can't remove build from review in iTunesConnect

Tags: build, app-store-connect, ios9

I know, there are questions like this on StackOverflow.

But this one is new... The itunesconnect UI changed a couple of days ago. Now I need to remove the build from review (Waiting for Review now), but there is no link to do so.

What should I do?

To reproduce this problem, upload a build into itunesconnect and submit it. Now how remove that build from review?

ScreenShot:
[image]

Maybe this explains what is happening, one build is processing forever (maybe it doesn't allow other builds to process?):
[image]

After 3 days waiting, the button finally appeared! Apple, please do fix this bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My Apps > App Store > iOS App

"remove this version from review." link is showing? You can remove build from review.

[image]

If this link not appearing, try rejecting the build on your iTunesConnect iPhone app.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/itunes-connect/id376771144?mt=8

[image]

Comment: I have no "remove this version from review" link on the web page and there is no "Reject this binary" in the app.

Comment: same as me. I'm not seeing the remove or reject link/button

Comment: Me neither. Added screenshot. I had this link a couple of days ago, but now it disappeared.

Comment: you saved me man 
i didnt have remove this version from review. from itunesconnect website 
but i can do that on the iphone application itunes connect thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to first upload a new binary with a new version number to be able to submit a new build. When the binary is finished to be processed, and only at that time, the dialog will appear at the top of the page.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have done that, in screenshot you can see that I uploaded 2 more builds after build 4.

Comment: This is probably a bug with their new UI. Uploading a new binary did the trick for me yesterday though. Maybe the bug is fixed since Oct 5th.

Answer (score 2):

missing link to remove from review can happen at times.

in such case, you should be able to reject the binary using iTunes Connect iOS app (or the newly released AppStore Connect app)